# finding the co-ordinates of a point given is an angle and a line segment

Tags: geometry

given with two  points A and B .i.e (x1,y1) ,(x2,y2).

and an angle .ie. BAC and distane length of AC .

how can i find the x and y co-ordinates of C ?

thanks in advance for your help .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let, in an orthogonal repere $OX$  $ OY$ :
$A=(x_A,y_A)$ , $B=(x_B,y_B)$ , $C=(x_C,y_C)$ 
$d(A,B)$ =length of the segment AB 
 
$d(A,C)$ =length of the segment AC 
$\alpha$ =angle formed by the segments AB, AC 
$\alpha_1$ =angle formed by the segments AB, OX (horizontal axe)

The $2$ unknowns are $x_C$ and $y_C$ 

We have:
$$x_C=x_A+d(A,C).\cos (\alpha-\alpha_1)$$ 
$$y_C=y_A-d(A,C).\sin (\alpha-\alpha_1)$$

expanding:
$$x_C=x_A+d(A,C).(\cos \alpha \cos\alpha_1+\sin \alpha \sin\alpha_1)$$ 
$$y_C=y_A-d(A,C).(\sin \alpha \cos\alpha_1-\cos \alpha \sin\alpha_1)$$

With the definition of $\alpha_1$, we have $t=\tan\alpha_1 =\frac{y_B-y_A}{x_B-x_A}$
Then $$\sin\alpha_1=\frac{t}{\sqrt(1+t^2)}=\frac{y_B-y_A}{d(A,B)}$$
     $$\cos\alpha_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt(1+t^2)}=\frac{x_B-x_A}{d(A,B)}$$

Put all together, we find :
$$x_C=x_A+\frac{d(A,C)}{d(A,B)}(\cos \alpha.(x_B-x_A)+\sin \alpha.(y_B-y_A))$$
$$y_C=y_A-\frac{d(A,C)}{d(A,B)}(\sin \alpha.(x_B-x_A)-\cos \alpha.(y_B-y_A))$$

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints.

- If you know the length of $AC$ (call it $r$) and you know the location of $A$ which is ($x_1, x_2$), what is the equation for the restriction on the location of $C = (x, y)$?  (Hint: use the distance formula.)
- If you know the angle $\angle BAC = \theta$, what can you say about the relation between the vectors $\vec{AB}$ and $\vec{AC}$?  (Hint: use the dot product.  You'll also need to express the vectors in terms of $x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2, x,$ and $y$.)
- This gives you two equations in the two unknowns, $x,y$.

Answer (score 0):

Using Geometry Expressions ...
[image]